# AutocompleteExtender css showing border even if collapsed

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using AJAX AutoCompleteExtender in my ASP.NET Website and am trying to figure out why is the border, or at least that's what I assume it is, showing under my textbox.

Notice in the picture on the left bottom corners of the two textboxes there is a 1by1px square. What can I add or change in my CSS to get rid of this?

[image: Sample]

This is my CSS:

```
.autocomplete_completionListElement
{  
overflow : auto;
max-height : 200px;
min-height: 0px;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
list-style-type : none;
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
width:auto;
background: #EBEBEB;
}
```

And this is the Textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_PostnaPosta" runat="server" CssClass="tBox" 
  autocomplete="off" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender 
  ServiceMethod="srch_tboxPosta" 
  MinimumPrefixLength="2"
  CompletionInterval="100" 
  EnableCaching="true" 
  CompletionSetCount="10" 
  TargetControlID="txt_PostnaPosta"
  ID="ac_txt_PostnaPosta" 
  runat="server" 
  FirstRowSelected="false"
  CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement">
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

*Not sure why the embedded picture is of potato quality, here is a direct link to Imgur* [Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuycX.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

border width is 1px in given css

```
.autocomplete_completionListElement
{  
  overflow : auto;
  max-height : 200px;
  min-height: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  list-style-type : none;
  margin:0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width:auto;
  background: #EBEBEB;
  }
```

Comment: Yes I tried this but then the dropdown looks awkward if there is no border. I also tried min-width:0px; thinking it might stay there because of width but it still shows.